# How to make my dialog fullscreen?

Tags: android, dialog

I have a Dialog class in which is instantiated somewhere to show a webview. As you see in the code below, it's not fullscreen. I've tried many changes but in best case, it is still not in fullscreen mode. What to do?

```
public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

static final float[] DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE = { 460, 260 };
static final float[] DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT = { 280, 420 };
static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams FILL = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
static final int MARGIN = 4;
static final int PADDING = 2;

private String mUrl;
private OAuthDialogListener mListener;
private ProgressDialog mSpinner;
private WebView mWebView;
private LinearLayout mContent;
private TextView mTitle;

private static final String TAG = "My-WebView";

public MyDialog(Context context, String url,
        OAuthDialogListener listener) {
    super(context);

    mUrl = url;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSpinner = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    mSpinner.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mSpinner.setMessage("Loading...");
    mContent = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    mContent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setUpTitle();
    setUpWebView();

    Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float[] dimensions = (display.getWidth() < display.getHeight()) ? DIMENSIONS_PORTRAIT
            : DIMENSIONS_LANDSCAPE;

    addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f), (int) (dimensions[1]
                    * scale + 0.5f)));
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
}

private void setUpTitle() {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mTitle = new TextView(getContext());
    mTitle.setText("My Site");
    mTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mTitle.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    mTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    mTitle.setPadding(MARGIN + PADDING, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
    mContent.addView(mTitle);
}

private void setUpWebView() {
    mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new OAuthWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
    mContent.addView(mWebView);
}

private class OAuthWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
//some code
}

public interface OAuthDialogListener {
    public abstract void onComplete(String accessToken);
    public abstract void onError(String error);
}
```

}

I've changed the below code, it makes the dialog larger but still not fullscreen:

```
addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                   display.getWidth() , display.getHeight()));
```

MyDialog is instantiated and started in another class like this:

```
 class A {
 //some code
 MyDialog mDialog = new MyDialog(context, mAuthUrl, listener);
 mDialog.show();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a dialogFragment instead. In it use the following code

```
public class myDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.NewDialog);
}
```

And declare the style in     values/styles.xml as

```
<style name="NewDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: well, still the constructor blocks me to do so. It's little complicated because some listener and other stuff are used in constructor which can't be changed.

Comment: You can still use your constructor and listeners, just change the dialog to a dialogFragment instead of dialog. Any particular listener that is blocking you from doing so?

Comment: after doing so, following parts are undefined to eclipse: Display display = getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
    (int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f), (int) (dimensions[1]
      * scale + 0.5f))); requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: The class format doesn't let me do the changes. In this case, i must change the overall class code.

Comment: Try this, keep it as a dialog and in its constructor, do the following:

public MyDialog(Context context, String url,
        OAuthDialogListener listener) {
    super(context,R.style.NewDialog);

    mUrl = url;
    mListener = listener;
}

Hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: Bad formatting on my end as well.. but the main difference is adding a second parameter of style when you call     super(context,R.style.NewDialog)

Comment: Yes it worked! I just copied the style.xml and replaced with mine. Then changed the line of code: addContentView(mContent, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(display.getWidth() , display.getHeight())); it works perfectly. thank you so much bro.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MyDialog mDialog =new MyDialog (this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
mDialog.show();
```

Comment: As you see, MyDialog class has it's own constructor and i can't change it.

Comment: Try this  mDialog .getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

Comment: I've already done. That change makes the mWebviw null and just mtitle remains!

Comment: Why set in manifest? it's not in manifest. However problem solved by above answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Java class**

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = width;
lp.height = height;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

**Style.xml**

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>


    <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```